# Error when using BootStrap 5 with Adonis and Inertia, with scss support

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5, inertiajs, adonis.js

Error when using BootStrap with Adonis and Inertia, with scss support.

I've been trying for days to make it work and I can't. Below is the configuration.

Would anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Grateful for the attention

webpack.config.js

```
Encore.enableSassLoader()
```

app.scss

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';

$primary: #000;

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Error

> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Deprecation Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is
> deprecated. In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be
> resolved by the browser. To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
> To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%}) More info:
> https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent
>
> resources\scss\app.scss 1:1                                divide()
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_grid.scss 85:13        @content
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_breakpoints.scss 68:5
> media-breakpoint-up() node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_grid.scss
> 72:5         make-grid-columns()
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss_grid.scss 38:3                @import
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 20:9            @import
> resources\scss\app.scss 9:9                                root
> stylesheet [ encore ] WARNING in ./resources/scss/app.scss
> (./resources/scss/app.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-13.use[1]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-13.use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-13.use[3]!./resources/scss/app.scss)
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Deprecation Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is
> deprecated. In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be
> resolved by the browser. To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
> To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%}) More info:
> https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent
>
> resources\scss\app.scss 1:1                                divide()
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_grid.scss 85:13        @content
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_breakpoints.scss 68:5
> media-breakpoint-up() node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins_grid.scss
> 72:5         make-grid-columns()
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss_grid.scss 38:3                @import
> node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 20:9            @import
> resources\scss\app.scss 9:9                                root
> stylesheet

Comment: See : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/39028

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While waiting for a fix, edit:

```
node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss
```

Replace percent with equal number

Result

```
@mixin row-cols($count) {
  > * {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: divide(1, $count);
  }
}
```

Comment: Solves the problem, but create new. "row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2...." completely buggy :/ So, waiting Bootstrap fixes that, I modified package.json like this: "sass": "1.64.2", and npm update

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is downgrading `sass` to `1.64.2`. It's work for me with Bootstrap 5.3.1

```
yarn add -D sass@1.64.2
```

or

```
npm install --dev sass@1.64.2
```